# Does XSD for WMS 1.3.0 request exist?

Tags: wms, xml, map-service, http-post

I'm running WMS service, that corresponds with OGC standard on WMS 1.3.0 - Queryable WMS "conformance class". It supports both mandatory requests - GetCapabilites and GetMap - and also optional request getFeatureInfo.

I was testing it with requesting the service by the method GET and I wanted to test it via POST request as well, but unfortunatelly, I wasn't able to create proper XML requests, because I haven't found any XSD schema on WMS requests. All I have found is XSD on capabilities (which deals with proper form of GetCapabilites document) and XSD on exceptions (which deals with exceptions format to be machin readable).

That forces me to think, that there is no possibility to request (properly) WMS service by POST request, or is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you an idea: http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/GetMap.xsd

Answer (score 4):

The schema for the HTTP POST encoding of a WMS 1.3.0 GetMap request is located at:

http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1/GetMap.xsd

(It's part of the SLD specification rather than the WMS specification presumably because it was thought that the only reason a client would have for issuing a POST request rather than a GET request would be to include custom user styles.)

I'm not sure where the official schema for the HTTP POST encoding of a WMS 1.3.0 GetCapabilities request is, or if there even is one.

Comment: that works fine for GetMap request, do you have any ideas on GetFeatureInfoRequest and/or getCapabilities? I know it's confusing to call these by POST, but still, is there an option?

Answer (score 2):

The format of OGC XML requests are specified in the [OGC Web Services Common Standard](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/common) document. Then WMS (and WFS, WCS, etc.) extends these schema to save time and effort.

If you have a look in http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/ you should find what you need. I don't have a good schema viewer to hand but http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/2.0/owsCommon.xsd should be a good point to look at.

Comment: I get that WMS, WFS etc extends basic OWS, but there is a [XSD file for WFS](http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd), that extends it. I have not found anything like that for WMS.